# ASTNode - qualifiedName.getFullyQualifiedName() does not return package name

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written a plugin that returns the fully qualified names for that code in the editor that my cursor lies on.

When the cursor lies on `WHITE` within the line `jButton[i].setForeground(Color.WHITE);`, I need to get the following information: `java.awt.Color.White`.

I am wondering why `qualifiedName.getFullyQualifiedName()` returns `Color.WHITE` without the name of the package.

Is there any possibility to get the name of the package except for extracting the name from what `qualifiedName.resolveBinding().getKey()` returns, i.e. `Ljava/awt/Color;.WHITE)Ljava/awt/Color;` ?

This is how I get the `qualifiedName`:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
ITextSelection sel = (ITextSelection) editor.getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
ITypeRoot root = JavaUI.getEditorInputTypeRoot(editor.getEditorInput());
ICompilationUnit cU = (ICompilationUnit) root.getAdapter(ICompilationUnit.class);
CompilationUnit compilationUnit = parse(cU);
NodeFinder finder = new NodeFinder(compilationUnit, sel.getOffset(),
    sel.getLength());
QualifiedName qualifiedName = (QualifiedName) finder.getCoveringNode();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that obtains the `qualifiedName` for you?

Comment: Hi Johannes, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the qualified name including the package yourself. Here is a basic example. You may need to add code to cover other situations.

```
IBinding nameBinding = qualifiedName.resolveBinding();
if (nameBinding != null && nameBinding.getKind() == IBinding.VARIABLE) {
    IVariableBinding variableBinding = (IVariableBinding) nameBinding;
    String result = variableBinding.getDeclaringClass().getQualifiedName() + '.' + variableBinding.getName();
}
```

A little word of warning when analyzing AST bindings. **Always** check bindings for being `null`. I can't stress this enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Johannes.